# Is volatile keyword extraneous for non-primitive values in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

If I have an ArrayList being accessed by two different threads, I know that with a int, you run the risk of reading off the thread's cache and receiving the wrong number. With an ArrayList, would the thread's cache only store the reference to the array? Meaning that the values inside the ArrayList would be consistent when accessed from either thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With an ArrayList, would the thread's cache only store the reference to the array?

A `volatile` write to an ArrayList only effects the assignment to the list field and not the mutation of the list itself (via `add` or `remove`).

> Meaning that the values inside the ArrayList would be consistent when
>   accessed from either thread?

No. Any modification of the list runs the same risk of non-volatile writes since, again, volatile only effects assignments of the volatile field.

---

You can define the `ArrayList` as `final` and get the same memory guarantees you would see if it were defined as `volatile` in regards to adding into the list or removing from.

Comment: Yes, same _guarantees_, but there is a difference.  Accessing a `volatile` variable can be quite costly, whereas accessing a `final` variable will be no more costly than accessing any other variable.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I was hoping to illustrate to the OP that declaring it `final` is 99% of the time better than declaring it `volatile` in his case.

Answer (score 0):

The volatile keyword does not only guarantee non-stale reads and atomic access (preventing word-tearing, especially on 32bit platforms) but also provides [ordering guarantees](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile), establishing a [happens-before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) relationship.

Normal field read/writes don't do that, which means if you write the array list reference to a non-volatile field and another thread reads it it might end up seeing the array list internals in an inconsistent state because the write got reordered with other writes.